# What features does vim-tiny have?

Tags: vim

So, the cut down `vim-tiny` is installed by default in Ubuntu. I don't mind using it, but I can't find documentation and most of the commands I'm used to from normal Vim don't work. So far I've discovered that `:n` and `:N` go between buffers and `:split` splits the screen (but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> does not), `:close` closes a split, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> hops between splits.

What other commands am I missing?

Comment: Wouldn't it be far simpler to just install vim than learn a new set of restrictions, limitations, and short cuts?

Comment: I can't upgrade to full Vim on every machine I SSH into. Besides, tiny-vim's capabilities probably won't fill an index card.

Comment: @James - even the most basic vi is going to be very powerful - try reading [Your problem with Vim is that you don't grok vi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118/3189) - the answer *only* covers vi, and therefore vim-tiny. Good luck with your index card ...

Comment: vi compatibility mode might be good to learn, in case you get stuck on a "vi" system.  vim-tiny (vi compatibility mode) has no help files.  <backspace> doesn't work.  "showmode" is not set, so zero prompts like "-- INSERT --" or "--REPLACE--" and need to intuitively know which mode you're in.  If you are a "VIM Expert" but get put on a "vi" machine, you could find yourself lost.  But if you know "vi compatibility mode" and get stuck with VIM, then it shouldn't be a problem, and can always go backwards if needed using ":set cp".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On 11.10:

```
$ vim.tiny --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct  6 2011 10:32:12)
Included patches: 1-154
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic -autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms -byte_offset -cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard -cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist -cmdline_info -comments 
-conceal -cryptv -cscope -cursorbind -cursorshape -dialog -diff -digraphs -dnd 
-ebcdic -emacs_tags -eval -ex_extra -extra_search -farsi -file_in_path 
-find_in_path -float -folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
-insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap -libcall -linebreak -lispindent 
-listcmds -localmap -lua -menu -mksession -modify_fname -mouse -mouse_dec 
-mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse -mouse_xterm 
+multi_byte -multi_lang -mzscheme -netbeans_intg -osfiletype -path_extra -perl 
-persistent_undo -printer -profile -python -python3 -quickfix -reltime 
-rightleft -ruby -scrollbind -signs -smartindent -sniff -startuptime 
-statusline -sun_workshop -syntax -tag_binary -tag_old_static -tag_any_white 
-tcl +terminfo -termresponse -textobjects -title -toolbar -user_commands 
-vertsplit -virtualedit +visual -visualextra -viminfo -vreplace +wildignore 
-wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 +xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard 
-xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -Wall -g -O2 -DTINY_VIMRC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo  -lselinux -ldl
```

There are only twelve features enabled (out of one hundred and twenty):

```
+builtin_terms      Some terminals supported
+cmdline_hist       Command line history
+fork()             Shell commands are forked
+iconv              Extra encoding conversions besides utf8<->latin1
+jumplist           jumplist history, 
                    So you can go back/forward with Ctrl-O/Ctrl-I
+multi_byte         Multibyte characters
+terminfo           Use terminfo instead of termcap
+visual             Visual mode supported (but no blockwise visual mode)
+wildignore         Allow wildcard patterns, to specify files to
                    ignore during filename completion
+windows            Support more than one buffer window
+writebackup        Backup files before overwriting (this either
                    provides this option, or defaults it to on)
+xfontset           X fontset support
```

The descriptions are based on the [feature list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+feature-list) link posted by @Caesium.

The missing keybindings etc may be because you are running vim in [vi compatible mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27compatible%27) - you can turn that off by doing `:set nocompatible` in vim or adding `set nocompatible` to you `.vimrc` file.

I did try `Ctrl-W s` and that did a split for me while running `/usr/bin/vim.tiny` while in compatible mode, so that might not be your problem. But I'm not sure what would be in that case. Maybe try making sure there is nothing in your `.vimrc` file that would stop that working.

Comment: how to enable features from the feature list?

Comment: @til you need to install a different version of vim

Answer (score 15):

Here you go:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+feature-list

Quote from :ve[rsion] ..

```
The first column shows the smallest version in which they are included:
T   tiny
S   small
N   normal
B   big
H   huge
```

I actually don't see any marked 'T' so it looks like you get just about nothing.. the other answer of "it's probably just about vi" might not be that far out ;)

Comment: Which version does /usr/bin/vim.basic correspond to, is it normal (N)?

Comment: `vim.basic` appears to be the 'huge without X'. It's the same as `vim-nox` in my anecdata gathering.