# What are the differences between vim.basic and vim.tiny?

Tags: vim, text-editor, update-alternatives

My favorite editor is Vim, so I decided to change the default editor of my ubuntu installation with the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

A prompt (with listed options) came up asking for an editor, but I noticed that it listed two *flavors* of Vim:

- /usr/bin/vim.basic
- /usr/bin/vim.tiny

What is the difference between the basic and tiny options?

Comment: Check out this comment about the differences: http://askubuntu.com/a/104202/284690

Comment: @terdon not really

Comment: @talles the linked question explains that `vim.tiny` is just a trimmed-down version of `vim`, presumably designed as a lightweight alternative and the accepted answer lists the `vim` features that are present in `vim.tiny`. Combined, they seem to answer your question perfectly. Don't they?

Comment: @terdon What about vim.basic? My question is precisely the difference between these two options. I'm sorry but a question that *might* have *some information* that *helps* it's definitely not an answer, it's just a helpful link. I don't want to start a debate here, but **it's definitely \*not\* a duplicate IMO**.

Comment: No debate, it's your question so if the other doesn't answer it then it's not a dupe by definition. I'm just trying to understand what else you need that is not explained there. Could you [edit] the question and clarify? `vim.basic` is just `vim`, and `vim.tiny` is a limited version of `vim`. You want to use `vim.basic` (or `vim.gnome` if that is installed and you want the GUI version). What else do you need to know?

Comment: @terdon So vim.basic it's just plain vanilla Vim? Didn't know that (man page doesn't state anything about it). Thank you. Next time try to *answer it* as an *answer* (rather than as a comment) ;)

Comment: Yes, `vim.basic` is just `vim` and is installed when you install the `vim` package (check with `apt-file vim.basic` or `dpkg -S /usr/bin/vim.basic`). I did not answer because I considered it a duplicate and answering a duplicate is a waste of effort for everyone involved. Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

So, **vim.basic** is just plain vanilla Vim (as you can check with `apt-file vim.basic` or `dpkg -S /usr/bin/vim.basic`).

While **vim.tiny**, as the name implies, is a *trimmed-down* version of Vim ([this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/104138/153234) explains it further).

---

Kudos for @terdon at comments for sorting that out.

Comment: When you say "plain vanilla Vim", there's a connotation that it's as opposed to some kind of "fancy spumoni Vim".  Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @DonHatch vim.basic can be called "plain vanilla vim" because it's what you get by default when you run `vim` from the command line. That is, `/usr/bin/vim` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/vim`, which by default is a symlink to `/usr/bin/vim.basic`.