# vim command does not work

Tags: 14.04, vim, execute-command, vi

I am trying to open `vim` on my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit by entering the command in the terminal :

```
vim
```

But i get the response :

```
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:
 * vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-athena
 * vim-gtk
 * vim-nox
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

But i assume( wrongly?) that vim comes by default in the distro. I confirm this by checking the installed packages :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/Desktop/packages
```

It lists `vim-common` and `vim-tiny`.

So why doesn't vim open up? On the other hand, if i enter the command `vi`, it opens up `vim` in `vi` compatible mode.

Comment: Visit : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1159206 Aslo http://askubuntu.com/q/281886/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it comes by default. Your mistake is that you think you should type `vim` to launch it. Just type `vim` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and you will get the command `vim.tiny`, which is the correct command.

If you need to run VIM by `vim` command, you should install `vim` package:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

You can read more about differences between them in [What features does vim-tiny have?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104138/what-features-does-vim-tiny-have)

Comment: Interestingly, the `vi` command used to open up vim in compatibility mode. Now after installing vim, the `vim` command works, but `vi` and `vim.tiny` now opens up the newly installed `vim` as well. I guess i have lost the default `vi` and `vim.tiny` editors that came with the Ubuntu distro.

Comment: default `update-alternatives` command modifies symbolic links in /etc/alternatives. The way the packages install by default might have changed.

Comment: This begs the question...why is it like this? Or, more briefly...WTF?